# Data Masking in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

In SQL server we do have **MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')** for dynamic data masking and the real content can be seen by only table owner.

Is there any other feature like this in Oracle.

I want to see the content only when logged in with table owner/sys, for rest it should be masked data for few columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, [VPD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm#DBSEG235)

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz, I saw that VPD used for accessing few rows but my requirement is to mask columns for other users.